# How to draw a JSON list in D3.js?

Tags: javascript, json, cakephp, d3.js, charts

I read that [JSON is built on two structures](http://json.org/).

I'm able to make a chart from a JSON list but the problem with CakePHP is that the output is in JSON object format.

How can I fetch my JSON object with D3 script?

(I use d3.v4.min.js)

**data.json**

```
{
    "result": [
        {
            "owner": "0",
            "variable": "Setpoint",
            "date": "2016-09-28T19:24:19-0400",
            "datas": 20
        },
        {
            "owner": "0",
            "variable": "Setpoint",
            "date": "2016-09-25T10:07:42-0400",
            "datas": 20
        }
   ]
}
```

**Script**

```
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// parse the date / time
var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%Z");

// set the ranges
var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

// define the line
var valueline = d3.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.datas); });

// append the svg obgect to the body of the page
// appends a 'group' element to 'svg'
// moves the 'group' element to the top left margin
var svg = d3.select("#debug").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform",
          "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// Get the data
d3.json("http://localhost/badina/datas/d3/0/Setpoint.json", function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;

  // format the data
  data.forEach(function(d) {
      d.date = parseTime(d.date);
      d.datas = +d.datas;
  });

  // Scale the range of the data
  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.datas; })]);

  // Add the valueline path.
  svg.append("path")
      .data([data])
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", valueline);

  // Add the X Axis
  svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

  // Add the Y Axis
  svg.append("g")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

});
```

Answer (score 0):

var data = data.result

```
d3.json("http://localhost/badina/data1.json", function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;
  var data = data.result
  console.log(data);
  // format the data
  data.forEach(function(d) {
```